# How to phrase this rigorously?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

Let $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$

$(x-y)^2 + (y-z)^2 + (x-z)^2 = 6$

Since $1 + 1 + 4$ is the only sum of 3 square numbers equal to 6, w.l.o.g. let $\,x\geq y \geq z$ so $x$ and $z$ have to differ by two, $y$ and $z$ by one and $x$ and $y$ by one. So all triplets $(x,y,z)$ of 3 consecutive integers should satisfy the equation.

Does this lack any rigor, if so, how would you phrase it properly or in a more mathematical notation?